# How to scale algorithm to fit in one frame and centered in the frame at same time?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, scaling, algorithm2e

Originally, the algorithm is too long to fit in the frame. If I use the `\scalebox{0.8}{}`, it can fit in the frame but doesn't look like to be centered in the frame. Here is the code and output. First picture is for the original code, second is for the code with scalebox. Are there any methods to make the the algorithm to **both fit in and be centered** in the frame. (And I think **the hat of A** in the last line is ugly.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Hello world}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
    %\scalebox{0.8}{ 
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} brow : \KwSty{int}$[M+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} bcol : \KwSty{int}$[N+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} val\_ptr : \KwSty{int}$[K+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[K]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[M+1]$\;
    \everypar={\nl}
    \ForEach{block row $I$}{
      $i_0 \leftarrow brow[I]$\;
      $r \leftarrow brow[I+1]$\;
      Let $\hat{y} \leftarrow y_{i_0:(i_0+r-1)}$\;
      \For{$b=ptr[I] \KwTo ptr[I+1]$}{
        $J \leftarrow ind[b]$\;
        $j_0 \leftarrow bcol[J]$\;
        $c \leftarrow bcol[J+1]-bcol[J]$\;
        Let $\hat{x} \leftarrow x_{j_0:(j_0+c-1)}$\;
        Let $\hat{A} \leftarrow a_{i_0:(i_0+r-1),j_0:(j_0+c-1)}$\;
        Perform $r \times c$ block multiply, $\hat{y} \leftarrow \hat{y}+\hat{A} \cdot \hat{x}$\;
      }
    }
      \end{algorithm}
      %}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply invert `minipage` with `\scalebox`, i.e. embed the `minipage` inside `\scalebox`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Hello world}
  \begin{center}
    \scalebox{0.75}{
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} brow : \KwSty{int}$[M+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} bcol : \KwSty{int}$[N+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} val\_ptr : \KwSty{int}$[K+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[K]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[M+1]$\;
    \everypar={\nl}
    \ForEach{block row $I$}{
      $i_0 \leftarrow brow[I]$\;
      $r \leftarrow brow[I+1]$\;
      Let $\hat{y} \leftarrow y_{i_0:(i_0+r-1)}$\;
      \For{$b=ptr[I] \KwTo ptr[I+1]$}{
        $J \leftarrow ind[b]$\;
        $j_0 \leftarrow bcol[J]$\;
        $c \leftarrow bcol[J+1]-bcol[J]$\;
        Let $\hat{x} \leftarrow x_{j_0:(j_0+c-1)}$\;
        Let $\hat{A} \leftarrow a_{i_0:(i_0+r-1),j_0:(j_0+c-1)}$\;
        Perform $r \times c$ block multiply, $\hat{y} \leftarrow \hat{y}+\hat{A} \cdot \hat{x}$\;
      }
    }
      \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}%
    }
  \end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The answer is OK for me. But I have a question why the hat of A in your picture is looks better than mine. Is there something should I notice?

Comment: @CodingTheLife No idea. Do you get any warning?

Comment: Yes. Here is the warning: || LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available ||LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences.

Comment: @CodingTheLife No, that has nothing to do with it. BTW, to remove that warning add the line `\let\Tiny\tiny` in the preamble. Try upgrading your TeX distribution.

Comment: @karlkoeller I use block inside scalebox, but that produces error. see this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kVSPBRm6j9/  expected output https://pasteboard.co/H8VivSp.png

Answer (score 2):

For content that contains text, choosing an appropriate font size is to be preferred over scaling the content, see [Why not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296) for some explanation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Hello world}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
        \scriptsize
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} brow : \KwSty{int}$[M+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} bcol : \KwSty{int}$[N+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} val\_ptr : \KwSty{int}$[K+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[K]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[M+1]$\;
    \everypar={\nl}
    \ForEach{block row $I$}{
      $i_0 \leftarrow brow[I]$\;
      $r \leftarrow brow[I+1]$\;
      Let $\hat{y} \leftarrow y_{i_0:(i_0+r-1)}$\;
      \For{$b=ptr[I] \KwTo ptr[I+1]$}{
        $J \leftarrow ind[b]$\;
        $j_0 \leftarrow bcol[J]$\;
        $c \leftarrow bcol[J+1]-bcol[J]$\;
        Let $\hat{x} \leftarrow x_{j_0:(j_0+c-1)}$\;
        Let $\hat{A} \leftarrow a_{i_0:(i_0+r-1),j_0:(j_0+c-1)}$\;
        Perform $r \times c$ block multiply, $\hat{y} \leftarrow \hat{y}+\hat{A} \cdot \hat{x}$\;
      }
    }
      \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

However if you don't mind a sub-optimal result, you could use one of the most evil beamer options: `shrink`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

% This solution is evil!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
% use it at your own risk!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\begin{frame}[shrink]{Hello world}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} brow : \KwSty{int}$[M+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} bcol : \KwSty{int}$[N+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} val\_ptr : \KwSty{int}$[K+1]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[K]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[M+1]$\;
    \everypar={\nl}
    \ForEach{block row $I$}{
      $i_0 \leftarrow brow[I]$\;
      $r \leftarrow brow[I+1]$\;
      Let $\hat{y} \leftarrow y_{i_0:(i_0+r-1)}$\;
      \For{$b=ptr[I] \KwTo ptr[I+1]$}{
        $J \leftarrow ind[b]$\;
        $j_0 \leftarrow bcol[J]$\;
        $c \leftarrow bcol[J+1]-bcol[J]$\;
        Let $\hat{x} \leftarrow x_{j_0:(j_0+c-1)}$\;
        Let $\hat{A} \leftarrow a_{i_0:(i_0+r-1),j_0:(j_0+c-1)}$\;
        Perform $r \times c$ block multiply, $\hat{y} \leftarrow \hat{y}+\hat{A} \cdot \hat{x}$\;
      }
    }
      \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```