# Long algorithm exceeds one page using algorithm2e package in IEEE Access Class

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

My long algorithm exceeds one page and will not fit on the page. I am using the `algorithm2e` package and the IEEE Access class. How to fit this long algorithm on one page?

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,ruled,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}



\begin{algorithm}
\tiny
\color{red}\caption{HGPDO Algorithm steps}
\label{algo:HGPDO Algorithm}
\textbf{A.} \textbf{Algorithm Inputs: } RTP, operation time duration, energy usage pattern, wind speed in \(m/s\), temperature, solar irradiance, efficiency, bio-gas availability, prior-scheduling pattern of appliances, BSS, CHP and EVSS initialization.\newline
\textbf{B. Parameters initialization:} Number of iterations, population size, $P_m$, $P_c$, $N$, $W_i$, $C_1$, $C_2$, $dimMin$, $dimMax$, $V_{min}$, $V_{max}$, $R_t$, $n$, $g$, $a$, maximum and minimum velocity, number of swarms, global and local pulls, initial and final momentum weights, cost per hour, PAR, $T_C$, $V_C$ and emission of CO$_2$.\newline
\For {Time=1:24 }
{
For initial position\newline
\For {hour=1:swarm}
{
\For {i=1:n}
{
\If {rand>0.7}
{
X=1
}
\Else
{
X=0
}
}
}
For initial velocity\newline
\For {vel1=1:10}
{
\For {vel2=1:6}
{
\If {Thour=0}
{
H=0
}
}
}
return $V_{best1}$, return $P_{best1}$\newline
For initial velocity and initial position,
Calculate  $Vel_{best1}$ and  $Pos_{best1}$\newline
 Generate population for WDO\newline
Assign position and velocity\newline
 \Begin
 {
 Based on $1^{st}$ position and velocity do evaluation of fitness  function\newline
        Using equations (\ref{eq:EQ1}) and (\ref{eq:eq2}) update the velocity and position respectively \newline
        $Vel_{best2}$, $Pos_{best2}$\newline
       based on $2_{nd}$ best position and velocity do evaluation of fitness function\newline
       Using equation (\ref{eq:eq3})-(\ref{eq:eq6}) update velocity,   position, check limits and boundaries, respectively \newline
       Evaluate the fitness for WDO \newline
       Check for $T_c$ and $V_c$ feasibility:\newline
      \If  {thermal comfort and visual comfort is less than WDO scheduled comfort}
      {
       Crossover $w_{best}$ and $g_{best}$, $Crossover_{result}$ = $cr_g$\newline
       }
        \Else
      {
        Crossover $Pos_{best1}$ and $Pos_{best2}$, $Crossover_{result}$ = $cr_g$, Mutate $cr_g$, $Mutation_{result}$=$global_{best}$
    }
    }

 returned $global_{best}$\newline
\textbf{C. Compute objectives: EBC, PAR, Carbon emission and UC}\newline
 \Begin
{
 \textbf{ 1. Compute user comfort} \newline
       \For {returned $global_{best}$, to calculate UC}
       {
           \textbf{a.} Usage power schedule=$global_{best}$ \newline
           \textbf{b.} Compute TC using equation (\ref{eq:eq41})\newline
           \textbf{c.} Compute VC using equation (\ref{eq:eq39})\newline
           \textbf{d.} Compute delay comfort using equation (\ref{eq:eq38})\newline
           \textbf{e.} Compute air quality comfort by equation (\ref{eq:eq42})
     }
      \textbf{2. Compute electricity cost} \newline
       \For {returned $global_{best}$, to calculate cost}
       {
        \textbf{a.} Only EG: $L_t=power$*$global_{best}$\newline
        \textbf{b.} EG with RES: Lt(RES)=Load-Energy from RES\newline
        \textbf{c. }EG with RES and BSS: Lt(RES and BSS)=Load-Energy procured from RES-BSS discharge\newline
        \textbf{d.} Compute EBC by Equation (\ref{eq:eq13}) for Case a, b and c
        }
          \textbf{3. Compute CO$_2$ emission}\newline
        \For {returned global-best, to calculate CO$_2$ emission}
        {
       \textbf{ a.} Only EG: average cost excluding RES and BSS\newline
       \textbf{b.} EG with RES: average cost including RES\newline
       \textbf{ c.} EG with RES and BSS: average cost including both RES and BSS\newline
       \textbf{d.} Compute CO$_2$ by Equation (\ref{eq:eq37}) for Case a, b and c
     }
      \textbf{4. Compute PAR}\newline
       \For {Operated returned global best, to calculate PAR}
       {
       \textbf{ a.} Only EG: $L_t=Power$\times$global_{best}$\newline
       \textbf{b.} EG and RES: Lt(RES)=Load- Procured energy by RES\newline
       \textbf{c.} EG, RES and BSS: Lt(RES and BSS)=Load- Procured energy from RES-BSS discharge\newline
       \textbf{d.} Compute PAR by Equation (\ref{eq:eq36}) for Case a, b and c
          }
    }
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A quick hint: You can tell the software to pretty-print chunks of LaTeX code by highlighting the lines in question and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the edit window. (That's the treatment I just applied to your code.)

Comment: While the algorithm2e cannot be split, it can be broken into cropped copies.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204703/multicols-not-breaking-procedures-in-algorithm2e/204792?r=SearchResults&s=3|26.9532#204792 for example.

Answer (score 1):

From the algorithm2e documentation document:
"Caution: **algorithms cannot be cut**, so if there is not enough place to put an algorithm with H option at agiven spot, LATEX will place a blank and put the algorithm on the following page"

So I believe your best option is to embed your algorithm inside a minipage or a resizebox. See [How to scale algorithm to fit in one frame and centered in the frame at same time?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220589/how-to-scale-algorithm-to-fit-in-one-frame-and-centered-in-the-frame-at-same-tim)

Comment: I think the OP's main issue is that the algorithm itself is taller than `\textheight`. Placing the `algorithm` environment in a `minipage` doesn't fix the height issue, and it's in fact bound to fail since one can't place a LaTeX float inside a `minipage`. If you try it, you'll get the dreaded `LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` error message.